# formula to offset from specific text and countif formula

Tags: excel

In F2, I have entered formula `IF(B2="","",IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,SUMIF($B$2:$B$7,$B2,E$2:$E7),""))` to give the sum of E2. I have dragged it down to F7 to give the sum of column E, per day. But I need it offset on the first row where the letters "sub" appear. F3 an F7 cells instead of F2 and F6. So, I added the offset function. Also, if you realised, in cell D, if there two subs with the same code as column G, it says YES twice. Is there a way to have it only once. I used formula `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sub",E1916)),"YES","NO")` and dragged it down. I have tried using the countif function taking column G as a reference but it doesn't work. Tried different ways and can't work it out. Would really appreciate your help with this. Many thanks

```
    B           C               D       E       F        G
2   01/01/2014  Max             NO              3       53
3   01/01/2014  Smith (Sub)     YES     2               54
4   01/01/2014  Nortor (Sub)    YES                     54
5   01/01/2014  Custis (Sub)    YES     1               55
6   02/01/2014  Barlo           NO              1       56
7   02/01/2014  Conie (Sub)     YES     1               57
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first request, I would just push the entire column F content down by one cell. So F3 would contain

```
=IF(B2="","",IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,SUMIF($B$2:$B$7,$B2,E$2:$E7),""))
```

that should be dragged down.

For the second request, using the following formula in D2 that is dragged down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Sub",C2)),"NO",IF(AND(B1=B2,NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Sub",C1)))),"","YES"))
```

The nested `IF` checks for a `Sub` on the same day (`B1=B2`) just above it.

[image]